inputing to a compiled c file with an .in file using the terminal
[enter image description here][1]I have a compiled c file and an input file (.in).
the input file contains the input I want to use while executing the c file, but I can't understand how I can do it through the terminal.
I tried using the cat command and the < > operators but all it got me is over writing the compiled c file with input written in the input file.
the input file content:
5
john
dani
john
johnny
joel
image of what i have tried
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iVEAEScj.png
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
 //==============================================================================

/** swaps two strings */
void swap(char** a, char** b);

/** Retrieves the maximal string by lexicographical order */
char* getLongestString(char** strings, int size);

/** Sorts and array of strings */
void sortStrings(char** strings, int size);

/** Reads an integer from the standard input */
int readSize();

/** Reads a string from the standard input and allocates memory for it */
char* readWord();

/** Reads strings from the standard input and allocates an 
array for them */
char** readWords(int size);

/** Frees the memory of an allocated array of strings */
void freeWords(char** words, int size);

/** Prints the required statistics of the strings array passed as parameter */
void printResults(char** words, int size);

//==============================================================================
void swap(char** a, char** b) {
char* temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}

char* getLongestString(char** strings, int size) {
char* max = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (strlen(max) < strlen(strings[i])) {
        max = strings[i];
    }
}
return max;
}

void sortStrings(char** strings, int size) {
bool changed = true;
while (changed) {
    changed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (strcmp(strings[i], strings[i + 1]) >= 0) {
            swap(&strings[i], &strings[i + 1]);
            changed = true;
        }
    }
}
}

int readSize() {
int size = 0;
printf("Enter number of strings:\n");
scanf("%d", &size);
return size;
}

void printResults(char** words, int size) {
char* longest = getLongestString(words, size);
printf("The longest word is: %s\n", longest);
sortStrings(words, size);
printf("The maximal word lexicographically is: %s\n", words[size]);
printf("The minimal word lexicographically is: %s\n", words[0]);
}

char* readWord() {
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "";
scanf("%s", buffer);
if (strlen(buffer) < 1) {
    return NULL;
}
char* str = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
if (!str) {
    return NULL;
}
return strcpy(str,buffer);
}

char** readWords(int size) {
char** words = malloc(size * sizeof(*words));
if (words == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    words[i] = readWord();
    if (words[i] == NULL) {
        freeWords(words, size);
        return NULL;
    }
}
return words;
}

void freeWords(char** words, int size) {
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    free(words[i]);
}
}

int main() {
int size = readSize();
if (size < 1) {
    printf("Invalid size\n");
}
char** words = readWords(size);
if (words == NULL) {
    printf("Error reading words\n");
    return 0;
}
printResults(words, size);
freeWords(words, size);
return 0;
}


Please provide a [mre] of "I tried using the cat command and the < > operators". My crystal ball shows me the error you made, but it is a little hazy and I do not want to make an answer on guesswork. Please [edit] and try for [ask] and consider taking the [tour].

-o mtm_bug.c is not what you want to build the binary, instead use -o mtm_bug (without the .c extension), then cat test1.in | mtm_bug or even simpler: mtm_bug < test1.in

i tried doing like you have suggested(also changing from mtm_bug.c to mtm_bug) but the terminal only sends the error message: "mtm_bug: command not found"

On unixes use the ./ notation, i.e. ./mtm_bug < test1.in to run the program in the current directory.

Either you code your main to handle stdargs or do : « cat .in | program.exe » which will replace the standard input by the contents of the .in file.

From what I see, your (dangerous! (do not use scanf!)) C program reads from stdin, not from a file. If you don't want to change this design, you have to redirect stdin so that it can be processed by this file. BTW, since your question focuses on how to invoke your program from the command line, you should also tell us which shell you are using.

the way david wrote worked perfectly"   ./mtm_bug < test1.in " thanks for all the help
